# javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-2.2

I gotten this error "javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /staffComposeMail.xhtml @55,218 value="#{emailBean.staffToEmail.firstName} #{emailBean.staffToEmail.lastName} (#{emailBean.staffToEmail.email})": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation" when I try to submit my form.

This is how my page looks like. The red underlined text represents the emailBean.staffToEmail.firstName, emailBean.staffToEmail.lastName and emailBean.staffToEmail.email respectively.

[image]

The input box inside one of my page

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" jsf:value="#{emailBean.staffToEmail.firstName} #{emailBean.staffToEmail.lastName} (#{emailBean.staffToEmail.email})"/>
```

Any idea on how to resolve this problem?

Edit : Added in emailBean

```
package managedbean;

import entities.Staff;
import entities.StaffEmail;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import sessionBeanInterface.emailSessionBeanLocal;
import sessionBeanInterface.staffSessionBeanLocal;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "emailBean")
@SessionScoped
public class EmailBean implements Serializable {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setStaffToEmail(new Staff());
        email = new StaffEmail();

    }

    @EJB
    private emailSessionBeanLocal emailSession;
    @EJB
    private staffSessionBeanLocal staffSession;
    private StaffEmail email;
    private String emailWithFirstName;
    private String personTo;
    private Staff staffToEmail;

    /**
     * @return the emailSession
     */
    public emailSessionBeanLocal getEmailSession() {
        return emailSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param emailSession the emailSession to set
     */
    public void setEmailSession(emailSessionBeanLocal emailSession) {
        this.emailSession = emailSession;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public StaffEmail getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(StaffEmail email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return the emailWithFirstName
     */
    public String getEmailWithFirstName() {
        return emailWithFirstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param emailWithFirstName the emailWithFirstName to set
     */
    public void setEmailWithFirstName(String emailWithFirstName) {
        this.emailWithFirstName = emailWithFirstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the personTo
     */
    public String getPersonTo() {
        return personTo;
    }

    /**
     * @param personTo the personTo to set
     */
    public void setPersonTo(String personTo) {
        this.personTo = personTo;
    }

    /**
     * @return the staffToEmail
     */
    public Staff getStaffToEmail() {
        return staffToEmail;
    }

    /**
     * @param staffToEmail the staffToEmail to set
     */
    public void setStaffToEmail(Staff staffToEmail) {
        this.staffToEmail = staffToEmail;
    }

    /**
     * @return the staffSession
     */
    public staffSessionBeanLocal getStaffSession() {
        return staffSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param staffSession the staffSession to set
     */
    public void setStaffSession(staffSessionBeanLocal staffSession) {
        this.staffSession = staffSession;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only assign a single value to the jsf:value attribute, like this:

```
jsf:value="#{emailBean.someString}"
```

Then, on your EmailBean, you could split this "someString" into the "firstName", "lastName" and "staffToEmail" attributes.